# Launch specific device simulator

Tags: mac, xcode, xcode-simulator

How can I launch the device simulator on a Mac and specify which specific device I want, for example an iPhone 6s or an iPhone X, without having to launch Xcode (which takes forever on my old Mac)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's one way (with two variations) to do what you want:

Begin by using Terminal to open the iOS Simulator.app's enclosing folder:

`cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/; open .`

Now you need to make a choice. If you use the Simulator often enough to keep its icon in the Dock, then go ahead and drag it in. If not, your other choice right click on the app's icon and select `Make Alias`, then drag the alias into the "Applications" directory.

All done in twenty seconds, and welcome to Ask Different!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `simctl` command from `xcrun`. Here's how to do it:

```
$ xcrun simctl list
```

Sample output:

```
(...)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 12.2 --
    iPhone X (AC5DA9BB-2198-4E6B-9CFC-A407730FF853) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone Xs (69A34565-5621-419C-8F37-3089FEFA52C1) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone Xs Max (8192F2B2-3F3F-49C1-AC36-D88550D48FCA) (Shutdown) 
(...)
```

The string in braces is UUID of the simulator device.

Boot the device with:

```
$ xcrun simctl boot $UUID
```

Now launch the simulator with:

```
$ open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/
```

If you do not need to switch the Simulator type, just run the last command.

More info about `simctl` and how to use it see the [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/simctl/) article.

Comment: Working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the device the simulator should run with using the `--simulator` flag, followed by the device name as a string.

In my case, I do: `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s"`